# MongoSocketOpenException when starting MongoClient with mongo-java-driver

Tags: java, mongodb, sockets, exception, mongo-java-driver

I'm running a java web server on Windows with a local MongoDB database using 
mongo-java-driver 3.2.2

When starting the server I create a new MongoClient:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost:27017", options);
```

(options contain some CodecRegistries)

Right after running the server I get the following log:

> com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger info
>
> INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
>
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
>
> ...

But then, after a few seconds, the server starts and I get the following log:

> com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger info
>
> INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:1}] to localhost:27017
>
> com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger info
>
> INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description
>   ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE,
>   state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2,
>   0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216,
>   roundTripTimeNanos=1691281}

I couldn't find a reason why the client would fail to connect for the first time and then recover but this behavior seems consistent with every run.

Did anyone come across similar behavior? If so, how could I solve the problem?

I'll provide any additional information if needed.

Answer (score -3):

turn off `mongodb` logger in `log4f.properties` like:

```
log4j.logger.org.mongodb = OFF
```

notice it is `org.mongodb` not `com.mongodb`